# Appending the innerhtml of <th>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to change a table cell with the current datetime but I can't seem to figure it out.

Here's the example: http://jsfiddle.net/mkjckt3b/

```
 $(document).ready(
  $("#date").html("Date of Report: " + currentDateNow());
 );

function currentDateNow(){
    var newDate = new Date();
    return newDate;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ready function is a little off, it should be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#date").html("Date of Report: " + currentDateNow());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call a line of code in a `.ready()`, you need to pass in a function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#date").html("Date of Report: " + currentDateNow());
});

function currentDateNow(){
    var newDate = new Date();
    return newDate;
}
```

Thus, surround the code in an unnamed function, and it will work.

### DEMO